# Multiple calls from a SIP

Tags: java, jain-sip

I want to make multiple calls from my SIP.
Now my program is written to make a single call.
How can i alter this to support more than one calls simultaneously?
can I make more multiple sipstacks ? if yes what would be there IP address? How would I differnciate them?
Or can i make multiple listening points in a single sipstack only?
thansk

Answer (score 0):

On a SIP phone the only way to make simultaneous phone calls is by using a VOIP service like SkypeConnect. For you to make the simultaneous calls you will need to subscribe to multiple channels on your SIP. Check out http://www.voicent.com/sip-faq.php for more details.

Answer (score 0):

why do u want to make multiple call from same sip phone simultaneously?

Anyways, IMO since sip uses port 5060 by default for both listening and sending, you cannot listen on the same port again. So, what you can do is listen on another port and contact another server.

Just change the ports from 5060 to say 5070, and the rest of the code would work fine, provided your sip server is also configured on that port; 5070 here...